# Use %%parametar from script in sql loader

Tags: batch-file, sql-loader

How to use %%G (return folder name) in sql loader in my script. In folder (%%G) a have files with extension like folder name. Example folder 0001\001.0001
Code:
`for /D %%G in ("*") DO (
    Pushd %%G
    set dir1=%%G
    sqlldr bods/password@SERVERBODS DATA=%dir1%/001.%dir1% CONTROL=ctl/001.ctl LOG=log/001.log BAD=bad/001.bad DISCARD=dsc/001.dsc
    Popd
 )`

Comment: I except DATA=0001/001.0001. "0001" is folder and inside this folder is file "001.0001"!

Comment: I would not assume that "*" would always yield a directory name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%g in ('dir /b /ad') do (
    pushd %%g
    echo data=%%~ng/001.%%~ng
    popd
)
```